# How to properly sync frames in freeglut?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut, vsync

How to enable something like v-sync in the freeglut program, is there a way to reduce screen tearing such as possibly properly syncing up the monitor refresh rate with the frames pushed out of the program? is there possibly a library that I could use that already contains something that could take care of this? I have found tutorials for "wglSwapIntervalEXT" but I have not found any simple tutorial in its bare form. I have my freeglut program in fullscreen and there seems to be screen tearing that I can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: What GPU do you have? Do you create a double-buffered context? Do you have proper drivers installed? To my best knowledge V-sync is turned on by default at least as far as nvidia is concerned.

Comment: Set swap interval to 1 and your program will do v-sync. There is no tutorial because it is too simple to make a tutorial around.

Comment: I am using intel integrated graphics. Ok, I am sorry that this question has an answer that seems to be a waste of time but for the life of me I cannot figure out the command to set the swap interval. Can you possibly link to an example code that shows swap interval in use? Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: When setting the display mode use double buffers. EG `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);`  At the end of the display function call `glutSwapBuffers();` If the GPU/Display device is configured to sync to the display you need only then call `glutPostRedisplay();`  If hardware is not set to sync you will have to use `glutTimerFunc(1000/60` but this will not be in sync with hardware only in tune/time (eg shearing will hover at a fixed pos on the display)